# Wordpress Custom Meta Query without wp functions (wo. wp_query())

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, title, meta

I have to fetch title, description and attachment out of the wordpress database without wp_query. I can't get how to fetch both, attachments and meta_descriptions at the same time...

This is how my query looks like so far

```
$query="SELECT post_title, meta_value 
FROM wp_posts p JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID=pm.post_id 
WHERE post_status='publish' 
AND post_type='page' 
AND post_parent=2330 
AND ( meta_key='_wpseo_edit_description' OR meta_key='_wp_attached_file' ) 
ORDER BY post_date DESC";
```

This query returns "doubled" results i have to split within a loop

```
______________________________
| post_title | meta_value    |
|------------|---------------|
|  title 1   | 1349          |
|------------|---------------|
|  title 1   | description 1 |
|------------|---------------|
|  title 2   | 1348          |
|------------|---------------|
|  title 2   | description 2 |
|____________|_______________|
```

Comment: please read [THIS POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) I wrote on how to ask a proper question, it will help you get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wlil need to join onto the `wp_postmeta` table in order to get any of the attached information, such as file attachments or custom fields.

An example of how to do this:

```
SELECT p.*, pm2.meta_value AS featured_image, pm3.meta_value AS wpseo_edit_description, pm4.meta_value AS wp_attached_file
FROM `wp_posts` p
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = 'wp_attached_file'
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` pm3 ON p.ID = pm3.post_id AND pm3.meta_key = '_wpseo_edit_description'
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` pm4 ON p.ID = pm4.post_id AND pm4.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND p.post_type = 'page' 
AND p.post_parent = 2330
```

The normal post fields (post title, description, ID, etc) will then be available, along with `featured_image`, `wp_attached_file` and `wpseo_edit_description`.

Comment: Whoa, your question has dramatically changed since I answered it.  I think my answer still stands, though.

Comment: had to change my question in cause of John Ruddell's hint

Comment: @Viktor thank you :) i wrote that to try and help others post better questions that we can understand and improve the community! :)